# C# Ver carpetas ocultas

Tags: c#

Lo que quiero hacer es cambiar la configuración de la computadora para que se puedan ver las carpetas ocultas y también para que no se pueda ver las carpetas no ocultas. Obviamente con codigo de C# sino se puede de cualquier otra manera....

Imagen de referencia
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder modificar eso vas a tener que hacerlo desde el registro, cambiando los valores del registro Hidden

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ModificarRegistro
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
            const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced";
            const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey;
            Console.WriteLine("1- Mostrar archivos ocultos");
            Console.WriteLine("2- Ocultar archivos ocultos");
            ConsoleKeyInfo reg = Console.ReadKey();
            if (reg.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
            {
                Registry.SetValue(keyName, "Hidden", 1, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
                Registry.SetValue(keyName, "SuperHidden", 1, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
                Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ShowSuperHidden", 1, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
            }
            else
            {
                Registry.SetValue(keyName, "Hidden", 2, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
                Registry.SetValue(keyName, "SuperHidden", 2, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
                Registry.SetValue(keyName, "ShowSuperHidden", 2, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente te agradezco pero al introducir el valor "1" y "2" solamente oculta todos los archivos con atributo oculto ¿estaré algo asiendo mal yo?

Comment: @Diego No, esta bien, eso es lo que consultaste en tu pregunta. Para lo que comentas ahora ademas deberias cambiar el atributo a los archivos. No olvides marcar como correcta si te sirvio la respuesta, saludos

Comment: Ok, gracias por la respuesta eso lo tendré en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

La [respuesta](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files) esta disponible en muchos lugares, dependiendo de la versión de Windows. La modificación de la configuración del usuario por programa tambien la puedes consultar en la [documentación de MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Cambios en la configuración de Windows se hacen en el registro.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816178/modifying-the-registry-key-value)

Si te refieres a [navegar o buscar en el directorio de archivos](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303974/how-to-recursively-search-directories-by-using-visual-c), lo pudes consultar tambien en la documentación de MS.

Comment: ¿puedes aclarar porque es una pregunta de C#?